# Works in Bash but not ZSH? .... alias ls='ls -lh'

Tags: zsh

```
alias ls='ls -lh'
```

Previously used this in bash to achieve default ls arguments

Trying to move to ZSH but have discovered this trick does not work.

Is there a preferred way to do this in ZSH?

thanks

Comment: What is the output of `type ls`?

Comment: "Does not work"?  Say what happens why you try.

Comment: People are overly critical on here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
   # echo $SHELL
   /usr/bin/zsh
  #alias ls='ls -lh'
  # ls
  total 32K
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 déc.  29 17:16 abc.txt
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 déc.  29 17:19 abd.txt
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 déc.  29 17:19 abe.txt
 drwx------ 2 root root 4,0K nov.  29 22:17 Desktop
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  100 déc.  30 14:33 test
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31 déc.  30 02:48 test.sh
 # echo $ZSH_VERSION
  5.0.2
```

Comment: OK I agree this works, thank you.  But not when I put it in my .zshrc?   Also I seem to loose my colours when I use this alias.

Comment: OK moving my command to the bottom of .zshrc fixed it... might be something in oh-my-zsh that clobbered my command.... Now to work on the colours :)  thanks

Comment: welcome , you can have colors if you include the --colour=auto in your alias `alias ls='ls --color=auto -lh'`